# Dynamically created Div's, children of outer Div, position wrong in Chrome, but correct in IE

Tags: javascript, html, json, cross-browser, position

I have some javascript which dynamically creates DIV elements containing data from JSON. I append these DIVs to a parent 'outerDiv'.

I want the OuterDiv to be a container that remains in the centre horizontally and butted against the top of window.

The inner DIVs I want then arranged within the container in a specific way.

I thought I had achieved what I wanted since it displays correctly in IE, but when I open it in Chrome, all the DIVs sit on top of one another within the outerDIV container.

Here is my code...

```
<script>

var data = { "users":[
    { "Club" : "Ashford",
    "Defeated" : false,
    "Score" : 520000,
    "Team Name" : "Assassins",
    "Id" : 1
  },
  { "Club" : "Eltham Hill",
    "Defeated" : true,
    "Score" : 480000,
    "Team Name" : "Crusaders",
    "Id" : 2
  },
  { "Club" : "Sittingbourne",
    "Defeated" : false,
    "Score" : 610000,
    "Team Name" : "Strikers",
    "Id" : 3
  },
  { "Club" : "Watford",
    "Defeated" : true,
    "Score" : 180000,
    "Team Name" : "Wanderers",
    "Id" : 4
  }
]}


var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");
outerDiv.id = "map";
document.body.appendChild(outerDiv);
//document.body.style.position='relative';
//document.body.style.left=200;

for (var z in data.users) {

    if (z % 2 == 0){
    var divTag = document.createElement("div");
    divTag.id = data.users[z].Id;
    divTag.innerHTML = "<H2>" + data.users[z].Club + "</h2>" + "</br> <h3>" + data.users[z].Score +"</h3>";
    document.getElementById('map').appendChild(divTag);
    document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.position='absolute';
    document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.left=10;
    document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.top=(data.users[z].Id - 1) * 100;
    document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.color='rgb(0,100,255)';
        }
    else {
    var divTag = document.createElement("div");
    divTag.id = data.users[z].Id;
    divTag.innerHTML = "<H2>" + data.users[z].Club + "</h2>" + "</br> <h3>" + data.users[z].Score +"</h3>";
    document.getElementById('map').appendChild(divTag);
    document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.position='absolute';
    document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.left=600;
    document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.top=(data.users[z].Id - 1) * 100;
    document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.color='rgb(200,10,20)';
        }
}



</script>
```

I have this CSS in Head at moment...

```
<style>

div h3 {color: green;}

div#map{
   width: 600px;
   height: 2000px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0%;
   left: 20%;

}
</style>
```

Why does it look correct in IE but not in Chrome?
I want it to look correct in all browsers, desktop and mobile.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Quick look:  There is no such html tag as </br>, it might be throwing off the 'good' browsers.

Comment: Thanks...That's not causing the issue though :(

Answer (score 1):

Done it...Something simple as I thought.

So it looks like IE adds 'px' onto the end of

```
document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.left=10;
```

and interprets it correctly

Chrome doesn't append the 'px' so I have just changed code to

```
document.getElementById(data.users[z].Id).style.left=10 + "px";
```

Should do that anyway really for best practise.